# What could cause an active filter (multiple feedback) to self oscillate?

Tags: active-filter, oscillation

I'm looking for a general description of what could cause a (multiple feedback) active filter to *self-oscillate*, what *parameters* as well as practical circuit *construction principles* affect it (prototyping).

Id like to know how can it be prevented in general, as well as for the specific example below. Answers like "you can tell from the (gain/Q/resistors/step response/whatever) that this is unstable, because ...", and what to do about it, will be much appreciated.
If you could point me to a hands on resource with best practices and gotchas, that would be great too.

This is for breadboard consumption, possibly with soldering, but not PCB design. You can assume that I use a filter design tool such as [Analog Filter Wizard](https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) or [Texas Instruments Filter Design Tool](https://webench.ti.com/filter-design-tool/), and have forgotten what academia tought me about poles and stability.

I provide a specific example for discussion, a 2 stage, 4-th order, multiple feedback Butterworth narrow bandpass filter of 10kHz built on a breadboard around [TL074CN](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl074.pdf), with dual LiPo battery supply +/-7.6V. Decoupling capacitors 0.1uF next to pins Vcc-Gnd and Vss-Gnd. TL074CN has a GBWP of 4-5MHz. There are no dangling wires except power in and signal out to an oscilloscope. Breadboard parallell lane capacitance is measured to roughly 2pF. The capacitors are cheap ceramic.

[image: Bandpass Filter-4th order Butterworth]

**Just the first stage in isolation, with *input R1_S1 tied to Gnd*, will self oscillate with Vpp 5V at around 9kHz** upon power on. Removing either R2, R3, C1 or C2 and reinserting it will stop the oscillation. The problem reoccurs when cycling the power supply.

The filter was designed using [Texas Instruments Filter Design Tool](https://webench.ti.com/filter-design-tool/), with the following parameters:

```
Bandpass Filter-4th order Butterworth
Passband: Ao: 1.000 V/V, Fc: 10 kHz, BWp: 550 Hz, Rp: 1.000 dB  Stopband: BWs: 1 kHz, Asb: -40.00 dB
```

The resulting stage gain is 1.52 and Q 25 and there is a warning which I wish I could understand, "Merit": `5% < Q < 15% or 5% < Wo < 10% or 5% < Gain < 10%`

Then, components were adapted to available values as follows:

```
C1_S1: 1nF -> 1.11nF +/-1% (cheap ceramic)
C1_S1: 1nF -> 1.07nF +/-1%
R1_S1: 270k -> 220k (tied to Gnd)
R2_S1: 820k -> 680k
R3_S1: 330 -> 220
```

The adaptation was trialled and verified using [Multiple Feedback Band-pass Filter Design Tool](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php). It is not important that the resulting center frequency is off, just the stability and gain issue.

The actual use of this filter example, is to clean up (and if possible amplify) a 10kHz +-100mV carrier wave from a capacitive sensor, riddled with mainly +-700mV mains noise.

**Edit: This particular oscillation stopped not with ground rewiring, but when increasing R3_S1 from 220 to not 330 but 390** (which, uncompensated, lowered fo to 7.4kHz).

Answer (score 4):

### [new & better Q>150 with low GBW](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%204%2028853.998118144256%0Aw%20280%20440%20264%20440%200%0Aw%20216%20376%20216%20440%200%0Aw%20320%20448%20320%20440%200%0Aw%20320%20440%20320%20376%200%0AO%20424%20304%20424%20272%200%0A170%20168%20440%20136%20440%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%20168%20344%20320%20528%203%20Box%0Ac%20216%20440%20264%20440%200%209.955948082265438e-10%200%0Ac%20216%20376%20264%20376%200%201.0000000000000003e-9%200%0Ar%20264%20376%20264%20440%200%20435748.00566496036%0Aw%20264%20376%20320%20376%200%0Ar%20168%20440%20216%20440%200%20108560.6562359191%0Ar%20216%20440%20216%20528%200%20546.7447769437931%0Ag%20216%20528%20216%20536%200%0Aa%20280%20448%20320%20448%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20320%20552%20320%20560%200%0AB%20320%20344%20472%20528%203%20Box%0Aw%20432%20440%20416%20440%200%0Aw%20368%20376%20368%20440%200%0Aw%20472%20448%20472%20440%200%0Aw%20472%20440%20472%20376%200%0Ac%20368%20440%20416%20440%200%209.955948082251525e-10%200%0Ac%20368%20376%20416%20376%200%201.0000000000000003e-9%200%0Ar%20416%20376%20416%20440%200%20467689.4200923812%0Aw%20416%20376%20472%20376%200%0Ar%20320%20440%20368%20440%200%20233328.5076643036%0Ar%20368%20440%20368%20528%200%20585.3466959526444%0Ag%20368%20528%20368%20536%200%0Aa%20432%20448%20472%20448%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20472%20552%20472%20560%200%0A174%20320%20480%20280%20528%200%20500%200.42080000000000006%20Resistance%0Aw%20280%20456%20280%20504%200%0Aw%20432%20456%20432%20504%200%0A174%20472%20480%20432%20528%200%20500%200.47030000000000005%20Resistance%0Ar%20320%20448%20320%20480%200%2033000%0Ar%20472%20448%20472%20480%200%2033000%0AS%20424%20304%20424%20336%200%200%20false%201%202%0Aw%20320%20376%20408%20336%200%0Aw%20472%20376%20440%20336%200%0AS%20634%20400%20634%20432%200%200%20false%201%202%0Ax%20345%20584%20461%20587%200%2024%20300R%20pots%20%0Ar%20320%20528%20320%20552%200%20200%0Ar%20472%20528%20472%20552%200%20200%0Ax%20547%20466%20695%20469%200%2024%20remote%20switch%0A)

link to SIM above...

@Wezzix reminded me of an old BPF design I used as a student, that I forgot now (senior's moment.)

[image]

It uses regenerative or positive feedback slightly less than Q of filter to reduce demands on GBW of the Op Amp to 1st order method. Even BETTER is the use of trimpots to tune double peaks for steep skirts but wider BW (Chebychev-like with small or large ripple)

BPF's operate by using a negative reactance to cancel a positive reactance. Using negative feedback as an impedance inverter with the multi feedback method. this is accomplished.  Then using positive feedback, when the R ratio approaches 1/Q (low), the Q increases to maximum and then drops rapidly. Thus by using a trimpot with a max ratio of 1.1% Vo and min ratio of ~ 0.6% Vo, one can tune for high Q and shift the f0 slightly at the same time to simulate a "double-tuned coil" used in all old FM IF BPF's to give steep skirts and wide flattop.

Thus the Q and centre fo can be simultaneously shifted within the Q range to adjust over all BW of both stages  ( I thought I invented this design) ha ;) so did someone else at Analog Devices ...

### SPECS

Fo = 10 kHz, BW= 1kHz (adjustable)
Ripple = adjustable, 0 to 3dB with BW
Gain = near Unity but adjustable with Q, BW, ripple with 2 trimpots using +Vo ratios selected ~ 1/Q nom.

Desired Bandstop rejection -20 dB @ +/-2kHz , Result = -25 dB with low ripple.

Great with low GBW. [image]

[image]

### old

( the above design is better with trimpots )

Oscillations occur from positive feedback in the ground reference to Vin+.  Since the attenuation ratio of your high Q BPF is about 50 with a very high gain, the GBW MUST be increased significantly to achieve this gain. In fact, for a 1st order filter GBW = Gain * BW, but for a 2nd order BPF the GBW MUST EQUAL fo * Q^2 = GBW to achieve the Q you design.  Ground impedance is raised by wire inductance which is 10nH/cm so use braid or multiple wide or Litz wire ground feeds for all grounds connected to a Power source. Do not cascade 2nd stage input shunt R to share the same path to Vin-=0V otherwise, the AC will feed into the Vin+ path and cause oscillations.

For Q=50 at 9kHz you need a GBW = 2500 * 9k = 25 MHz GBW. Got it?  component tolerances must be equally small to make the 2 stages identical, otherwise you will see two peaks after the oscillations have been eliminated.  With a Ground plane I have achieved Q=100 over all the Audio band with adjustable Q and variable f using a different design with almost constant gain and variable Q using a pot on output to FB with the other filter design technique with positive feedback. (S&K method)

I won't go into the math like @jonk but I designed this as part of my voice (whistle) activated remote control for quadrapalegics in my grad thesis almost 50 yrs ago. But he can as I once did.

### Alternative design method

1. Define SNR spectrum by amplitude and frequency inputs.
2. Define output SNR the same
3. The difference is your filter shape for -3dB and -n*6dB/octave or say -40 to -60 dB down for noise and n poles
4. Choose n/2 OA's with Q^2fo=GBW and depending on skirt rejection noise threshold and number of octaves away , determines number of stages.
5. This may result in raising your -3dB BW thus raising component tolerances significantly from 0.01% to 0.1%  for high Q being relaxed from 40 to 20 or lower while achieving high SNR. Yet your noise is unknown so far.
6. Bessel and other linear phase types will also have lowest Q for each pole and lowest group delay distortion.
7. Cheby. Filters have steeper slopes but massive band edge group delay distortion
8. For biphase data, one would use Raised-Cosine filters instead for lowest or zero ISI.
9. Scale all R values up and C values down by same constant such that you know the effects of OA driver loading on smallest R.
10. To eliminate DC offsets match Rin's with bypass cap for input bias currents or check if necessary.
11. If any results are not achievable such as R >30M or GBW >100 MHz, there are better ways with video amps with high gain 40 dB and 50 MHz BW or 200 MHz GBW  and well over 1GHz. In RF passive filters are used without feedback or SAW filters or ceramic, Xtal filters. I have used 16kHz and 23 kHz Xtal filters using 2 stages of 5 deg cut Xtals for WWV and uV level signals in North Pole. To get global position movements in the '70's.

Comment: Great, the TI tool said GBW > 37MHz, and now I understand why (Total Q^2 * Stage gain * fo = 50^2*1.519*1e4). I would request some clarifications: Could insufficient GBW in fact cause oscillations, or simply degraded performance (low gain is indeed the case in the example)? Also, the breadboard has two Gnd lines running along the sides to which which Vin+ and R3 resistors are connected. Could this indeed be a problem, and any idea how to solve it? Like copper tape ground plane, or wiring all to a central point?

Comment: No,  Yes.   and twisted magnet wire for longish interconnects  and close to IC decoupling caps for higher PSRR.  I got Q= 100 with 1 stage with S&K and pot for feedback gain. But you are best off using Bessel BPF filters design for 4th order.\ which have lowest Q

Comment: Also the tolerance of your passive parts is squared as well with Q , so prepare to measure C to 4 sigfigs. Otherwise reduce skirt slope demands and for 8th order filter with a quad OA. then you can relax tolerances to 0.1% and get 100 MHz GBW OA's https://rocelec.widen.net/view/pdf/7jnraplskh/slos408b.pdf?t.download=true&u=5oefqw

Comment: The other problem is current limiting driving 330 Ohms so scale up from TI's design tool. higher R and lower C

Comment: Wow, you're packing a bunch of useful info into the comments :) To interpret, I should use twisted wires, with the second wire tied to ground. Except for ground connections, which has (any single cables to) a ground plane. Lower Q will reduce GBW and component tolerances, but also widen the transition band. Did you mean a 8th order can get same slope as 4th order with lower Q or lower tolerances? And rescaling components, the only way I know how to, is the link I posted with trial and error, per stage, until fo and gain are maintained. Anything else to keep in mind here? Noise consideration?

Comment: U got it. CMOS > 100MHz GBW, same -3dB and -40dB BW using relaxed tolerances and lower Q in each pole with BESSEL with 8 or more poles increase all Rx10 and C/10 use preamp low Q if ness. To raise SNR to get adequate >100 mV output without saturating front end with noise

Comment: I read your method 20 times, and I think, in my case, the output SNR is undefined because it's currently an experiment for maximum sensor range and I have zero experience. I found something interesting. Using the Analog filter wizard produces a very different design with 2 additional "Q resistors", essentially 20:1 positive feedback gain. I notice 3 things: (1) R1 > R2, (2) there is a slider to adjust capacitor/resistor sizing, and (3) the recommended GBW is only ~1MHz due to "complicated math". Playing with (2) I can get fo +/- 6dB for 1% tolerance. Any drawback to this design/Q-resistors?

Comment: that is a method to promote oscillation by regenerative feedback to raise Q but with gain <1  . Have  your specs changed from ? Filter-4th order Butterworth
Passband: Ao: 1.000 V/V, Fc: 10 kHz, BWp: 550 Hz, Rp: 1.000 dB  Stopband: BWs: 1 kHz, Asb: -40.00 dB